# Get user details who like facebook page and post on page

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I've following requirement and I want to confirm if it's possible or not and if possible then any helpful link? I have to implement this in codeigniter:-

"Facebook-Application which can be integrated to a Brand-FB-Site. The app should award clients (-> Login to app via phone number) with points for each engagement on the facebook-fanpage. The points can be redeemed for vouchers (e.g. to buy products in their web-store (independent from FB) or to get discounts on their monthly mobile phone contract)."

Comment: _“The app should award clients […] with points for each engagement on the facebook-fanpage”_ – stop right there, that’s not allowed. You/your client should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) first of all. Point 4.5 being the most relevant here, _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ – so for any other kind of “engagement”, you are not allowed to reward the user in any way.

Comment: #CBroe:- Can I somehow detect if user liked my fb page? user should have to login from my app first before liking page. I never worked on fb before so I need help about what I can do and what data fb returns when user like page. Thanks

Comment: No, you can not detect if the user likes a single, specific page any more. (In theory you can – but Facebook will not allow you to use the necessary permission for such a purpose.) “Like gating” is not allowed any more, so you are not allowed to treat users that liked your page and those who didn’t differently.

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing, can you provide me the link of facebook documentation where it's written that facebook doesn't gives detials about user who like page?? I have to inform my boss that it's not allowed. Many thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_90_day_deprecations mentions that Facebook will not allow the use of the permission for that purpose; and https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+like+gating will shows you lots of resources mentioning that Facebook doesn’t allow “Like Gating” any more.

Comment: thanks alot. you saved my day (y)

Comment: @CBroe Hi again, I got new requirements, I've to detect following details:

->User post or share something on our page
->User like other's post on our page
->User comments on any post on our page

can we get these details?

Comment: Yes that is possible; but this question is getting a bit too broad now – so I’d ask you to go check the documentation yourself first. You want to look at the `page` object and its `feed` edge, and maybe also into Real-Time Updates.